# TypeScript and Html2Canvas?

Tags: javascript, typescript, html2canvas

Does anyone know if there a TypeScript definition file (d.ts) available for the Html2Canvas library?

Html2Canvas is a great library for taking screenshots of a browser using JavaScript. See https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas for more details.

Comment: npm install --save @types/html2canvas

Answer (score 0):

Since version `1.0.0-rc.2`, types were added to `html2canvas` package in npm. So if you install it using

```
npm i html2canvas@1.0.0-rc.2
```

or install the higher versions, you can use `html2canvas` with typescript.